# "async Task" member questions

Tags: c#, async-await

What does this code actually do?

```
public async Task Foo()
{
}
```

You get a warning that since `Foo` does not `await`, it will be run synchronously. Is it exactly equivalent to `public void Foo()`? Why is it valid to return `Task`, but not actually create and return one?

Similarly, what does the following do?

```
public async Task Foo()
{
    await SomeOtherAsyncFn();
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you write `public async Task Foo() {}`, the compiler actually goes through and creates a state machine with no states, which immediately returns the `Task`.  There's a lot of extra overhead that serves no purpose, which is why there's a compiler warning in place to avoid this.

It would be far simpler/more efficient to just write:

```
public Task Foo()
{
    return Task.FromResult(true);
}
```

This would provide the same API, in a simpler manner.

> Similarly, what does the following do?
>
> ```
> public async Task Foo()
> {
>     await SomeOtherAsyncFn();
> }
> ```

This causes the compiler to create a state machine which will return a `Task`.  It will immediately call `SomeOtherAsyncFn` when you call `Foo()`.  The `Task` returned will be marked completed as soon as `SomeOtherAsyncFn()` finishes.  The state machine will also handle bubbling up exceptions cleanly for you in this case, so the exception will get mapped into the `Task` properly if one occurs in `SomeOtherAsyncFn()`.

Comment: And of course for the second exmaple you can also just write `return SomeOtherAsyncFn();` and have the method *not* be `async` to avoid the state machine and all of the overhead that comes with it.

Comment: Thanks! So does that mean `async Task Foo() { /* some non-awaitable work here */ }` is *functionally* the same as `void Foo() { /* some non-awaitable work here */ }`?

Comment: @moswald Yes - though it returns a `Task` that will be "completed", and goes through a lot of work to get there.

Comment: Why doesn't the compiler just skip the generation of the state machine stuff when there's no await?

Comment: @user2674389 It could - but it doesn't.  As for why, I think it's because you're explicitly saying you want it by using the `async` modifier - it warns you that it's not necessary, but it's still there.

Comment: @ReedCopsey Would be interesting to know what they thought. :-) Since there is no "use async when I have await, else not"-keyword.

Comment: @user2674389 Yeah - well, there is a compiler warning - ignore warnings at your own risk :)

Comment: @user2674389: I have a speculation on why:  For methods with more than a few lines of code, it could happen that changing a method from async to synchronous would not get noticed by the developer just from all the clutter.  2¢ worth.